# How to use the go-mysql-driver with ssl on aws with a mysql rds instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ssl, go

I have a RDS instance running on AWS and I want to know how to connect to that instance over ssl.

From this link [Using SSL with mysql database](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html#MySQL.Concepts.SSLSupport). AWS sets up our database registered with a certificate and provides the root certificate for download.
[AWS rds root ca](https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem)

Now the go-mysql-driver provides this information in there documentation to setup an ssl connection.

```
rootCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
pem, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/path/ca-cert.pem")
if err != nil {
   log.Fatal(err)
}
if ok := rootCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(pem); !ok {
   log.Fatal("Failed to append PEM.")
}
clientCert := make([]tls.Certificate, 0, 1)
certs, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("/path/client-cert.pem", "/path/client-    key.pem")
if err != nil {
   log.Fatal(err)
}
clientCert = append(clientCert, certs)
mysql.RegisterTLSConfig("custom", &tls.Config{
                         RootCAs: rootCertPool,
                         Certificates: clientCert,
                        })
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user@tcp(localhost:3306)/test?tls=custom")
```

The example indicates that I need a client certificate and client key.

But amazon only provides the root certificate. How can I use that with go-mysql-driver to connect to my mysql instance?

Answer (score 14):

I'd add a comment to the previous answer, but my reputation isn't high enough. This is working for me:

```
    rootCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    pem, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/path/ca-cert.pem")
    if err != nil {
       log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if ok := rootCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(pem); !ok {
       log.Fatal("Failed to append PEM.")
    }
    mysql.RegisterTLSConfig("custom", &tls.Config{
                             ServerName: "qcaurora.cb556lynvxio.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
                             RootCAs: rootCertPool,
                            })
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:pass@tcp(qcrds.example.com:3306)/databasename?tls=custom")
```

The only change from the above is the addition of the ServerName field. I've also clarified the address field for use with a CNAME dns entry and using a password. If you don't use a CNAME to RDS, you could leave out the ServerName field.

I'm using go 1.11 with go-sql-driver/mysql version v1.4.1.

Answer (score 4):

From looking at the docs [here](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql) and [here](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#RegisterTLSConfig) and [here](https://godoc.org/crypto/tls#Config), it looks like you simply need to set the `RootCAs` value to the root certificate you obtained from AWS. You don't need to set the `Certificates` value since you aren't using a client cert. So the code would look something like:

```
rootCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
pem, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/path/ca-cert.pem")
if err != nil {
   log.Fatal(err)
}
if ok := rootCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(pem); !ok {
   log.Fatal("Failed to append PEM.")
}
mysql.RegisterTLSConfig("custom", &tls.Config{
                         RootCAs: rootCertPool,
                        })
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user@tcp(localhost:3306)/test?tls=custom")
```

Comment: This appeared to work however when I run a query against my mysql database. I get the following errors.                                                          [mysql] 2017/02/11 14:23:14 packets.go:33: unexpected EOF
[mysql] 2017/02/11 14:23:15 packets.go:33: unexpected EOF
[mysql] 2017/02/11 14:23:15 statement.go:27: invalid connection                       So it looks like the connection doesn't actually work.                                       Any other ideas on how to get this to work?